# How can I compile and edit VC++ 2003 solution with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have VC++ Visual Studio 2003 solution, I need to upgrade it to Visual Studio 2010 because of editor feature and other else

How can I edit it and compile it with Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Make a copy of the visual studio 2003 files as backup then just open the visual studio 2003 solution using visual studio 2010.  Normally a later version of visual studio will convert an solution file from an older version.  I have done this from visual studio 6.0 to visual studio 2005 and from visual studio 2005 to visual studio 2012.

Comment: You may have to do some fixup work.  For instance help files may need some changes, a problem I had going from visual studio 6.0 to visual studio 2005 with the change from the old style RTF files to the new HTML files for help text.  However the new help compiler converted them for me.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project in the solution explorer and choose properties. 
There should be a Platform Toolset in the General entry.
Change that one to the current version of Visual Studio.